# JSON input to ColdFusion webservice + RestFul

Tags: json, web-services, coldfusion, cfc

I have written one webservice (cfc) in ColdFusion which accepts JSON input data and I am returning http status code after authenticating.
My question is - How to catch/accept JSON data in ColdFusion, in the FORM Scope???

I have written two ways to accept JSON, and I am unsure. Can anyone please help.

FIRST WAY:

```
<cfscript>
  record=deserializeJSON(
'{
"customerId": #Form.CustomerID#,
"userName": "#Form.userName#",
"password": "#Form.Password#"
}'
);

this.customerid = record.customerId;
this.userName = record.userName;
this.password = record.password;
 </cfscript>
```

I am parsing the input json and getting it in a struct and then setting parameters in a variable.

SECOND WAY:

```
<cfif (cgi.content_type EQ "application/json")>

        <cfset record = deserializeJSON(ToString(getHTTPRequestData().content))>
        <cfscript>
this.customerId = record.customerId;
this.userName = record.userName;
this.password = record.password;
 </cfscript>

</cfif>
```

Can Anyone please help me understand how to catch JSOn input data in ColdFusion?

Comment: I am looking at your use of `deserivalizeJSON()` and I think you are going the wrong way. I think you want to build a struct, then serialize it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've phrased your question I'm not sure what you're asking?  Looking at your code it looks like you want to convert form submission values into JSON?  If so, just do this:

```
<cfset myJSONForm = serializeJSON(form)>
```

If you're capturing JSON it should be easy as long as the JSON is formatted properly:

```
<cfif isJSON(form.jsonString)>
    <cfset myJSONvar = deserializeJSON(form.jsonString)>
</cfif>
```

Comment: No, actually I want to convert JSON values into variables. I will be receiving the json input.